# Validators for checking taken usernames doesnt work properly

Tags: angular, typescript

So i have this validator:

```
takenUsername(control: FormControl): Promise<any> | Observable<any> {
    const promise = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      let text$ = fromEvent(this.userName.nativeElement, "keyup")
        .pipe(
          debounceTime(200),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          switchMap(() => this.employeeService.getEmployeeList())
        )
        .subscribe((employees) => {
          if (employees.length === 0) {
            resolve(null);
          }
          const properties = employees.map((employee) => employee.userName);
          for (let tempProperty of properties) {
            if (tempProperty === control.value) {
              resolve({ usernameIsTaken: true });
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
          }
        });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

For some reason it will check only the first item i have in a collection. I know the logic in othe places work because if i delete all the objects and add some again, only the first one will be matched as taken. on the other ones it doesnt.

I tried inserting some console.log:

```
const properties = employees.map((employee) => employee.userName);
          for (let tempProperty of properties) {
            console.log("temp property is " + tempProperty)
            console.log("control value is " + control.value)
            if (tempProperty === control.value) {
              resolve({ usernameIsTaken: true });
            } else {
              resolve(null);
            }
```

The results are:

control value is ciao

temp property is l

control value is ciao

temp property is ciao

control value is ciao

temp property is dasd

control value is ciao

So "ciao" is not the first element in the table, so i dont get any error. If i tried with the first one, this logic seems to work and resolve the error usernameIsTaken

Comment: Are you actually getting your entire employeeList on every keystroke...?

Comment: No that's why i put the debounce time. How would you do it otherwise? I thought of getting it only on Init and then doing the comparison with a local array of employees, but cant they be like "hacked" and modified in this way?

Comment: Ideally you sent the username string to a backend process that checks the name and just returns true or false (available or not)..

Comment: so im using spring data rest. in the employee repository what method should i use? for search for example i use findByUserNameContaining.

Comment: Sorry man, can’t help you with Spring..

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is never completed because the Promise you have created resolves with `null` as soon as it finds a username that isn't taken. I'd also advise maintaining your Observable chain all the way through and not using Promises. Something like this:

```js
takenUsername(control: FormControl): Observable<any> {
  return fromEvent(this.userName.nativeElement, "keyup").pipe(
  debounceTime(200),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(() => this.employeeService.getEmployeeList()),
  map(employees => {
    const foundEmployee = employees.find(employee => employee.userName === control.value);
    if (foundEmployee) {
      return { usernameIsTaken: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: But wait the console log show that the loop actually ends...if the promise resolve shouldnt the method be exited?

Comment: maybe im missing something i reference the validator with this.istakenUsername.bind(this) but it doesnt seem to work with your code